# App crashes on received gcm message when it's closed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-messaging

When my app is closed (i.e swiped off by the user from the App Switching menu), it crashes in `onMessageReceived()`.

Here's `onMessageReceived()`:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    from = data.getString("sender");

    File notificationsFile = Constants.getNotificationsFlagFile();
    ...
}
```

It crashes on that last line, giving a `null pointer exception`:

> 08-13 21:15:25.535  23201-23216/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>           at com.example.myapp.chatGCM.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:52)
>           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzs(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzk(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
>           at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at helpers.Constants.(Constants.java:54)
>               at com.example.myapp.chatGCM.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:52)
>               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzs(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzk(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
>               at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

and here's `getNotificationsFlagFile()`:

```
public static File getNotificationsFlagFile()
{
    return new File(MainApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir(), "notifications_"+getSession());
}
```

and finally:

```
private static String getSession()
{
    File file = new File(MainApplication.getAppContext().getFilesDir(), "session");
    int length = (int) file.length();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        try {
            in.read(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return (new String(bytes));
}
```

All I'm using is static variables and functions. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) you seem to be having an un-expected behavior... Probably from the `getAppContext()` function... try using `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: You're somewhat right. `getAppContext()` is a static method in `MainApplication`, and it returns `MainApplication.context;` , which gets initialized in `MainApplication`'s `onCreate()`. Being the app closed, it hasn't been "created" yet.