# Android: Call MyGCMListenerService not work

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I use GCM for notification

Register token work full but receiver not work

> MyGCMListenerService.java

```
public class MyGCMListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

        if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
            // message received from some topic.
        } else {
            // normal downstream message.
        }

        sendNotification(message);
    }


    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

For start receiver use intent in mainactivity

> MainActivity.java

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(G.currentActivity, MyGCMListenerService.class);
        startService(myIntent);
```

> Error Log :

```
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-03 20:38:29.491: E/AndroidRuntime(10971):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Can you help me for this problem ?

> Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.aloonak.app.network.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.aloonak.app.network.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.techcasita.android.push"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".MyGCMListenerService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".RegistrationIntentService" android:exported="false">
        </service>
```

Comment: The `GcmListenerService` is automatically started when a GCM message arrives. You must not start it manually.

Comment: Thank you, but not work auto for me ! how fixed it ?

Comment: One thing that might help is posting the contents of `AndroidManifest.xml` to make sure everything is configured correctly there.

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan updated post

Comment: Couple things here. I'm assuming you only posted the relevant parts of the manifest so I'm assuming the permission settings are outside the application element and the receiver and services are inside it. If that isn't the case then update the manifest so it is. Also, the category of the `intent-filter` for the receiver is supposed to be the application id. There you put `com.techcasita.android.push` but you use `com.aloonak.app.network` in the permissions where application id is also supposed to be used. Update it with the correct value whichever it is.

Comment: Thank you , Is correct ? <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="com.aloonak.app.network"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: Yes. If `com.aloonak.app.network` is what your application id is in the build.gradle file then that should be correct. If you get that working it is also useful to know you can use `${applicationId}` in the manifest file. This will be replaced with your actual application id during [manifest merging](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html).

Comment: Change but not worked

Comment: How are you testing? Did you register the device to receive GCM messages by getting a [token](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID#public-methods)?

Comment: Yes, i save token to my server. if application close, notification send to my mobile and worked. but if application open not receive notification

Comment: Do you see the `Log.d()` messages that you have in `onMessageReceived()` in both cases ?

Comment: No i don't. nothing set log for both ! if application close , title and content get from google GCM. provided my code for send notification is different

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995818/app-crashes-on-received-gcm-message-when-its-closed